# Form dynamic query and execute in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I want to form a dynamic query for drop and create view and execute it.

```
for C in Cursor  
LOOP 
ViewName :='View_'|| ID; 
DropViewSQL := DropViewSQL || 'DROP VIEW '||ViewName ||';' ; 
CreateViewSQL := CreateViewSQL || 'CREATE VIEW '|| ViewName ||' AS SELECT * from xyz;';                    
END LOOP;
```

**//Some Insert and update statements to be executed before drop and create view basically i want to create a new view after these Insert and update statements**

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DropViewSQL);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CreateViewSQL);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE DropViewSQL;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CreateViewSQL;
```

This gives error - PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

I want to execute this dynamically formed query.

**Solution:**

I have used array instead of cursor to store the resultset. Performed the insert update and then loop on array.
Thanks for the suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple statements in one `execute immediate` call; you'd need to call that inside the loop:

```
for C in Cursor
LOOP
  ViewName := 'View_'|| C.ID;
  DropViewSQL := 'DROP VIEW ' || ViewName ;
  CreateViewSQL := 'CREATE VIEW ' || ViewName || ' AS SELECT * from xyz';

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DropViewSQL);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CreateViewSQL);

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE DropViewSQL;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CreateViewSQL;
END LOOP;
```

Notice that the dynamic SQL statement does not have a semicolon on the end. You also might not need to do a separate `drop` step; `create or replace view` might be more appropriate, since that retains grants.

Without any further information about the 'Some statements to be executed before drop and create view' part it isn't clear where those would fit in.

But that doesn't explain the PLS-00382. You haven't shown what `Cursor` is, and I suspect it doesn't like that. Since `cursor` is a reserved word yours (hopefully) won't be called that, but don't know if it's an explicit cursor declared earlier or an implicit cursor with the query in-place here. Either way you need to show what that is and what it is doing. If that is OK then maybe one of the other statements you're removed is causing the error. Without all the relevant code and the line number of the error, it's hard to guess.

---

If you really have to generate the commands together, then do something else before executing them, you could store them in a PL/SQL table:

```
DECLARE
  cursor cur is select view_name as id from user_views;
    /* or whatever your real cursor is */
  type sqltab is table of varchar2(200);
  dropsqltab sqltab;
  createsqltab sqltab;
  viewname varchar2(30);
BEGIN
  dropsqltab := sqltab();
  createsqltab := sqltab();
  for C in cur
  LOOP
    ViewName := 'View_'|| C.ID;
    dropsqltab.extend();  
    dropsqltab(dropsqltab.count) := 'DROP VIEW ' || ViewName ;
    createsqltab.extend();  
    createsqltab(createsqltab.count) := 'CREATE VIEW ' || ViewName
      || ' AS SELECT * from xyz';
  END LOOP;

  /* other commands */

  FOR i IN 1 .. dropsqltab.count LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(dropsqltab(i));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(createsqltab(i));
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dropsqltab(i);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE createsqltab(i);
  END LOOP; 
END;
/
```

You still haven't said what relationship, if any, there is between the drop/create statements and the insert/update statements. If they are related you can extract values from the PL/SQL table more than once. If they aren't, well, I don't understand the restriction on the order things are done.

Comment: Thing is i can not execute these drop and create view commands in the loop itself before that i need to do some insert and updates.. Also I can not loop this after those statements as I loose values in cursor after execution of it.

So I need to form those queries of drop and create view
Do some insert update
And then execute drop and create view queries formed..

Comment: I mean to say the flow is-
1. Form drop n create view queries
2. do some insert/update i.e. required before creating new views
3. then execute the drop n create view queries

Comment: @user1049021 - please update the question to show what you're doing between creating and executing the dynamic statements. I'm afraid it isn't clear why the insert/update (of what?) need to be done in between.

Comment: @user1049021 If you are recreating the same view why not to boil down those two `DDL`s to one - `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` preserving all privileges granted to those views if any were granted?